How do ClusterIP services route traffic to pods if they're distributed across multiple nodes?
My understanding of how ClusterIP services are implemented is that the ClusterIP resolves to a kube-proxy within a node that routes traffic to the underlying pods within the node. If that's the case, how does traffic get routed to pods if they're distributed across multiple nodes? Is one node elected a leader and is traffic destined to the ClusterIP always routed to it or is there some kind of internal load balancing implemented to distributes the traffic across nodes?

Requests can reach any of the replicas; beyond knowing that, the mechanics don't really matter to application developers.  Virtual IPs and Service Proxies in the Kubernetes documentation describes the specific mechanism.

Yeah I've read through that page but I didn't see anything about how traffic gets routed across nodes, it's more focused on the internals of routing within a node.

ClusterIP services are load balanced - that means every TCP connection that is opened  / UDP interchange typically gets the next pod in the list of endpoints for a given service. (You can get the endpoints via kubectl get endpoints).
The routing is done by the container runtime and may differ per implementation of the container runtime or the used network plugin (usually via CNI).
So, if you access a service and the pod behind the endpoint is on the same machine the network gets routed locally. When the pod is running on another machine the network gets tunneled to the other machine and there is again routed to the correct port by the container runtime / network implementation. How the network packets are tunneled depends mainly on the CNI implementation you use (e.g. Calico, Cilium, ...). For example Cilium uses eBPF instead of iptables to get better performance on big clusters.
See also Cluster Networking in the Kubernetes documentation.

Two follow up questions:

Does the cluster ip resolve to a single node?
If the above is correct and if the 'next' pod in the list is on a node other than the one pointed by the cluster ip, does the cluster ip node route traffic to that node that contains the next pod?

Just trying to understand your explanation in relation to the original question about pods being on separate nodes and how traffic gets distributed to each.

The cluster IP is just a virtual IP - the networking system of Kubernetes maps this on opening the connection  to the destination node/container (which is usually selected as round-robin).

The kube-proxy doesn't act as a router itself, but instead creates iptables DNAT rules (or ipvs rules if run in ipvs mode). Any node in the K8S cluster that you reach via the  ClusterIP will translate it to one of the Pod IPs behind the service with equal probability, thus balance between the Pods.
Here is a simple example created in the killercoda playground (uses Canal as CNI):
Create a simple deployment with three pods:
controlplane $ k create deploy test --image=nginx --replicas=3
controlplane $ k expose deploy test --port=80
controlplane $ k get svc test -o wide
NAME   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
test   ClusterIP   10.96.103.104   <none>        80/TCP    8s    app=test

Kubernetes has taken the service's IP 10.96.103.104 from the service-network defined in the api-server config. This IP does not appear on any interface, but is part of a DNAT rule.
To see the DNAT rule for the "test" service look into the KUBE-SERVICES chain in the nat table:
controlplane $ iptables -t nat -S KUBE-SERVICES |grep test
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.103.104/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/test cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-HQOVHX4BQRA7XPPR

Traffic to the service IP on port TCP/80 is send to the chain KUBE-SVC-HQOVHX4BQRA7XPPR.
In that chain traffic is equally distributed to further chains called KUBE-SEP-*. The comments in these rules already indicate, that the will forward the traffic to the pods of this deployment (192.168.1.4-6):
controlplane $ iptables -t nat -S KUBE-SVC-HQOVHX4BQRA7XPPR
(..)
-A KUBE-SVC-HQOVHX4BQRA7XPPR -m comment --comment "default/test -> 192.168.1.4:80" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.33333333349 -j KUBE-SEP-AF2XNHZ3XSY64BHD
-A KUBE-SVC-HQOVHX4BQRA7XPPR -m comment --comment "default/test -> 192.168.1.5:80" -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-V7JEUCB5YAVYFLNA
-A KUBE-SVC-HQOVHX4BQRA7XPPR -m comment --comment "default/test -> 192.168.1.6:80" -j KUBE-SEP-7GWD7DT7TZ3AREWA

And if you look at the KUBE-SEP-* chains, you finally see the DNAT that forwards to the individual Pod IPs.
controlplane $ iptables -t nat -S KUBE-SEP-AF2XNHZ3XSY64BHD
(..)
-A KUBE-SEP-AF2XNHZ3XSY64BHD -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/test" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.4:80

controlplane $ iptables -t nat -S KUBE-SEP-V7JEUCB5YAVYFLNA
(..)
-A KUBE-SEP-V7JEUCB5YAVYFLNA -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/test" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:80

controlplane $ iptables -t nat -S KUBE-SEP-7GWD7DT7TZ3AREWA
(..)
-A KUBE-SEP-7GWD7DT7TZ3AREWA -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/test" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.6:80

Now that we are dealing with Pod IPs, the CNI will have created routes to these IPs already.
In the example it is the route for 192.168.1.0/24 to the flanel.1 VXLAN interface. This is what connects the "controlplane" node to "node01" where the pods are running.
controlplane $ ip route show
(..)
192.168.0.2 dev cali6a8a832c000 scope link 
192.168.0.3 dev calid92c4054772 scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink <=== Routes into a VXLAN tunnel created by the canal CNI

If I had added tolerations to my deployment, some of the pods could be running on the "controlplane" node as well, and would then use one of the more specific /32 routes like for the Pods with 192.168.0.2 and .3 here.
How the routing actually looks like, is dependent on the CNI.
See this comparison of the most common ones. The video explains how routing works in detail.

So are the kube-proxy's DNAT rules capable of routing traffic to pods on other nodes?

No, the DNAT rules only translate Service-IPs into Pod-IPs before routing takes place (it is a "prerouting" operation). For Pod-IPs you will have routes installed by the CNI (like shown in the last code-block with "ip route show" in my example). Those routes live in the kernel's routing table, the CNI / kube-proxy orchestrates creating/deleting/updating those routes.

Just stumbled over the term "resolves to (..) a node" in your question. What derkoe and I wrote, is all about cluster internal traffic (ClusterIPs only work from nodes within the cluster).
Is it possible that you actually wanted to ask: "How do I access my ClusterIP from outside the cluster?"
If that is the case, take a look a "BareMetal Loadbalancers" like MetalLB or PureLB (my favorite). They allow you to create LoadBalancer services in on-premises clusters without using NodePorts.
